# MongoDB MongoEngine index declaration

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I have Document

```
class Store(Document):
    store_id = IntField(required=True)
    items = ListField(ReferenceField(Item, required=True))
    meta = {
        'indexes': [
            {
                'fields': ['campaign_id'],
                'unique': True
            },
            {
               'fields': ['items']
            }
        ]
    }
```

And want to set up indexes in items and store_id, does my configuration right?

Answer (score 2):

Your second index declaration looks like it should do what you want. But to make sure that the index is really effective, you should use [explain](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/). Connect to your database with the mongo shell and perform a find-query which should use that index followed by `.explain()`. Example:

```
db.yourCollection.find({items:"someItem"}).explain();
```

The output will be a document with lots of fields. [The documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#explain-output-fields-core) explains what exactly each field means. Pay special attention to these fields:

- **millis** Time in milliseconds the query required
- **indexOnly** (self-explaining)
- **n** number of returned documents
- **nscannedObjects** the number of objects which had to be examined without using an index. For an index-only query this should be equal to **n**. When it is higher, it means that some documents could not be excluded by an index and had to be scanned manually.

Comment: [`indexOnly`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#explain.indexOnly) isn't really self-explaining: it indicates a covered query. In this special case all of the fields in the query **and** all of the fields in the result are part of the same index.